# Kibana search pattern issue

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to create a elastic search query for one of my Library projects. I am trying to use regex but I do not get any result. I am trying to enter the following regex query.

```
GET /manifestation_v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "bibliographicInformation.title": {
        "value": "python access*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

access is a wildcard so i want to create a query which takes as python access* not python access

Can anyone help me out who already has some experience in kibana?

Comment: That doesn't work either have tried it @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: according to documentation
 * : Repeat the preceding character zero or more times. For example:
ab*     # matches 'a', 'ab', 'abb', 'abbb', etc. Is this exactly what you want?

Comment: So basically i am creating a search query for my library which lists in all the books which has python access* where * can be any wildcard character.So if i search for python access i get it but if i try to search python access* i do not get any hits. @sabasafavi

Comment: can you add your index mapping in question? being text or keyword is important

Answer (score 0):

You need to run regex query on keyword field and use .* instead of *

ex.

```
GET /manifestation_v1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "bibliographicInformation.title": {
        "value": "python access.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regex is slower , you can also try prefix query

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
      "bibliographicInformation.title": {
        "value": "python access"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If field is of nested type then you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

**Update**

For "text" type , field is stored as tokens. i.e
"python access" is stored as ["python","access"]. You query is trying to match "phython access*" with each of these tokens individually. You need to query against keyword field , which is stored as single value "phython access".

Comment: Had tried previously too does not work either. So my question lies basically that if i just hit access* I am getting the hits but if I try python access* I do not get any hits.

Comment: @NehalTrivedi your field type is "text". Do you have subfield of type "keyword". can you add your mapping in question

Comment: subfield meaning a keyword field under title?

Comment: @NehalTrivedi , yes.  Field in query will change to bibliographicInformation.title.keyword.

Comment: I tried with that too, It doesn't work wanted to check if the regex which I am writing is correct? Because there is a white space in between 2 words.

Comment: @NehalTrivedi Can you add your mapping , latest query you are using and a sample document in question

Answer (score 0):

you can try wildcard query

```
{
  "query": {
          "wildcard": {
            "bibliographicInformation.title": {
              "value": "saba safavi*"
            }
          }
        }

}
```

Comment: Tried that too. This doesn't work either if i try safavi* i am getting hits but when i try saba safavi* I do not get any hits.

Comment: Same hits as the last regex nothing is changing even though i tried wildcard